# How to change the NOTIFICATION HUBS billing tier using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-notificationhub

i need to change the notification hub tier free to standard using power shell script. help me on the script. i didn't find anything.

I have tried using auto scale setting , but its not working.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To change billing tier you need to update your namespace.

Notification Hubs namespace can be created/updated using Service Bus management APIs. Here's an article on [how to create a namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-powershell-how-to-provision#provision-a-service-bus-namespace), and another one on [how to create a hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-deploy-and-manage-powershell#provisioning-a-new-notification-hub). Updating should be very similar to those.

Alternatively, here's the [REST API to create or update a Notification Hubs namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/namespaces#Namespaces_CreateOrUpdate).

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can use the below request body to change the tier. This is using the Service Management API mentioned in the link above

Request Method: PUT

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/{namespaceName}?api-version=2016-03-01
```

Request Body

```
{
  "Location": [Resource Location],
  "Tags": null,
  "Properties": {    
    "NamespaceType": "NotificationHub"
  },
"sku":{
    "name":"Standard"
  }  
}
```

Below is the powershell script example you can use to update the tier. You need to install the azure powershell sdk.

```
$skuTier = "Standard"
Set-AzureRmNotificationHubsNamespace -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup -Namespace $namespaceName -Location $location -Tags $tags -skuTier $skuTier -Force
```

Comment: Set-AzureRmNotificationHubsNamespace : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'skuTier'.
At line:1 char:127
+ ... tion "West US" -skuTier $skuTier -Force
+                    ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureRmNotificationHubsNamespace], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.NotificationHubs.Commands.Namespace.SetAzureNotificationHubsNamesp